# Evaluate integral from sympy as lambda function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, lambda, sympy

I'm using the sympy module of python. I do is this:

```
x= Symbol('x')
integrate(x**2+2,x)
```

The answer is:

```
x**3/3 + 2*x
```

Now, the question is this: Is there a way to make this answer a lambda function of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `lambdify`:

```
>>> f = lambdify(x, integrate(x**2+2,x))
>>> f(2)
6.666666666666666
```

If you want to use this with numpy, set `"numpy"` as the second argument of lambdify

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> f = lambdify(x, integrate(x**2+2,x), "numpy")
>>> f(np.arange(10))
array([   0.        ,    2.33333333,    6.66666667,   15.        ,
         29.33333333,   51.66666667,   84.        ,  128.33333333,
        186.66666667,  261.        ])
```

(you'll probably want to `import numpy as np` and `import sympy as sp` and not import names directly if you do this, since functions from the two do not mix)